# Split number into groups by magnitude

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

given an input `34567890`

I want an output: `[34, 567, 890]`

I can do it with some modulo math and floor division

```
num=34567890
output_list = []
division_tracker = num
while division_tracker > 0:
    output_list.insert(0, division_tracker%1000)
    division_tracker = division_tracker//1000
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I would probably say no, but I don't know what you would consider "better".

Comment: You can string them and slice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of hacky, but:

```py
>>> list(map(int, f'{34567890:,}'.split(',')))
[34, 567, 890]
```

`f'{n:,}'` generates a string of the integer `n` with commas as thousands separators, we split the resulting string at comma and cast the parts into `int`.

Comment: Equivalently, one could do `[*map(int,'{:,}'.format(34567890).split(','))]`

Comment: I must admit that I don't really see the point, since it's slower than using a modulo.

Comment: @Cubix48 It's quicker to write this way, at least

Answer (score 2):

credit goes to @fsimonjetz

if you want to use list comprehension instead of map:

```
[int(x) for x in f'{34567890:,}'.split(',')]
[34, 567, 890]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a *slice approach* over strings:

```
s = str(345678)
n = len(s)
r = n % 3 # remainder

groups = [int(s[r + 3*i:r + 3*(i+1)]) for i in range(n//3)]
if r != 0:
    groups = [int(s[-r:])] + groups

print(groups)
```

**EDIT**

A *regex approach*: nested gropus are not allowed so the pattern is constructed explicitely, based on the amount of digits.

```
import re

s = '12345678235156721'

regex = ''
if (r:=len(s) % 3) != 0:
    regex += '(\d{{{}}})'.format(r)
regex += '(\d{3})' * (len(s) // 3)
regex = r'{}'.format(regex)

grps = list(map(int, re.search(regex, s).groups()))
```

Output

```
[12, 345, 678, 235, 156, 721]
```